# How to persuade that test users give their UDIDs for Ad Hoc Distribution?

Tags: ad-hoc-distribution

My app is currently well-developed but not released on App store. 40 volunteers are willing to test my app. I want to let them test my app by Over The Air (OTA) Ad Hoc distribtuion.
However, since i need their UDIDs to set their iPhones as test devices on iOS provisioning portal, test users might not want to give such private information.
Besides, does provisioning file contain all the UDIDs of test users?
I am afraid of that all the UDIDs would be known if someone opens the provisioning file.
Are there experienced developers who already successfully persuade test users to give their UDIDs for Ad Hoc distribution?

Since a company will contact test users, they said it's really hard to ask test users' UDIDs. Is it any second solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that it is awkward to ask people for their UDID.

There is a free app that will let them automatically send their UDID to you. I find it's not only easier to persuade test users to use it, it also makes the process easier for them.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ad-hoc-helper/id285691333